# php What is the correct way to execute a WebSocket server?

Tags: php, websocket

I'm trying to execute **server.php** which is a server for websocket to work (Rachet websocket),
I tried this code below, but the problem is script always hangs at that line when calling `shell_exec()`,
I also tried using `exec()` same problem
Code:

```
$result = shell_exec('php ../bin/server.php > chat_logs.txt &');
    if ( empty($result) )
    {
        echo 'Error, not executed!';
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to execute a server application from another PHP script? Not clear what the use case is here. If you're running a websocket server it generally needs to be running all the time - triggered from a command-line, or better still as a daemon which runs at startup. Pretty sure Ratchet have some documentation about that. What are you actually trying to achieve with the above script? Please provide some context.

Comment: I am trying to execute a websocket server on web server but couldn't accomplish this because of that hanging problem when I call `shell_exec()` & `exec()` functions

Comment: Yes you already said that. But my point was that it doesn't make sense. **Why** are you trying to do it this way, instead of running the socket server as a proper background service? Maybe you don't fully understand the architecture or something, I don't know.

Comment: It seems pretty obvious it will hang the PHP script, because the socket server will be configured to run indefinitely (because _it's a server!_), so it will never return from shell_exec.

Comment: So what' is the best approach to accomplish my needs

Comment: I already mentioned it: Run it as a background service so that it's always available, and then you can make wss connections to it whenever necessary. Did you read http://socketo.me/docs/deploy yet?

Comment: please can you give me some code on how to run server in background, becuz I dont understand the deployment in that page

Comment: Why what specifically is the issue with those instructions? Did you try any of it? What went wrong? What part is confusing you?

Comment: What confusing me is that Supervisord is not for windows systems

Comment: Ok. So have you done any research by yourself into what might be an equivalent on Windows?